# C Passing char array to function using structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

We have a small program where the input comes from a text file (see text sample below) and is used to scan and write certain student information to different struct variables. However, when the **add_student()** function is called it gives this bizzare output (see screenshot below).

```
struct student_list sl;
struct teacher_list tl;

struct data {
 char *name;
 int number;
 char index;};

struct student {
 struct data *d;
 struct student *next;};

struct student_list{
 int size;
 struct student *front;
 struct student *tail;};

struct teacher{
 struct data *d;
 struct teacher *next;};

struct teacher_list{
 int size;
 struct teacher *front;
 struct teacher *tail;};

void main()
{   
    readAndLoad();

    print_students();
}
    void readAndLoad()
{
    int c;
    int i=0;
    char line[200];
    int number, semNum;
    char name[100];
    char index;

    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c != '\n')
        {
            line[i++] = c;
            line[i] = '\0';
            /*printf("%c ", c);
            printf("%s \n", line);*/
        }else
        {
            //printf("\n");
            int j, b; 
            b = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < sizeof(line); j++) 
            {
                if (line[j] == ' ')
                ++b;
            } 

            //printf("%s \n", line);

            if (b == 2)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'S')
                {
                    sscanf(line, "S %d %s", &number, name);
                    struct student *studentnode;

                    studentnode = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
                    add_student(&studentnode, number, &name);
                } else if (line[0] == 'T')
                {
                    sscanf(line, "T %d %s", &number, name);
                    struct teacher *teachernode;

                    teachernode = malloc(sizeof(struct teacher));
                    add_teacher(&teachernode, number, &name);
                }
            }

            memset(&line[0], 0, sizeof(line));
            i=0;
        }
    }
    //printf(line);
}

void add_student(struct student *n, int student_number, char *student_name)
{
//---------------------------------------------------
    printf("%s\n", student_name);
    n->d->name = student_name;
    n->d->number = student_number;
    n->d->index = 'S';
    n->next = 0;
    printf("%s\n", n->d->name);
//---------------------------------------------------
    if (sl.size == 0)
    {
        sl.front = n;
        sl.tail = n;
        printf("%s %d \n", n->d->name, n->d->number);
    } else
    {
        sl.tail->next = n;
        sl.tail = n;
        printf("%s %d \n", n->d->name, n->d->number);
    }

    sl.size++;
    printf("Student added\n");
}

void add_teacher(struct teacher *n, int number, char *name)
{
    n->d->name = name;
    n->d->number = number;
    n->d->index = 'T';
    n->next = 0;

    if (tl.size == 0)
    {
        tl.front = n;
        tl.tail = n;
    } else
    {
        tl.tail->next = n;
        tl.tail = n;
    }

    tl.size++;
    printf("Teacher added\n");
}
void print_students()
{
    int i;
    struct student *s = sl.front;

    for (i = 0; i < sl.size; i++)
    //while (s->next != 0)
    {
        if (i == (sl.size - 2))
        {
            printf("%c %s %d", s->d->index, s->d->name, s->d->number);
        } else
        {
            printf("%c %s %d \n", s->d->index, s->d->name, s->d->number);

            s = s->next;
        }
    }
}
```

[Input text file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWvdA.png)

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJQSw.png)

Between the highlighted part //------------------- 
in the code we can see a correct output of the name from the first printf() but when we go to the second printf() it only prints the blank space... Do you know what could be the problem?

**Input text file:**

```
S 123456 Ivan
S 654321 Georgi
T 123456 Jesper
T 123457 Ole
T 123458 Lars
T 123459 Erland
C 31 CALI1 3
C 11 WDDI1 1
C 21 SDJI2 2
E 123456 31
E 123456 11
E 654321 21
A 123456 31
A 123457 11
```

**Console output:**

```
Ivan

 123456
Student added
Georgi

,▒( 654321
Student added
Teacher added
Teacher added
Teacher added
Teacher added
E 0▒( 2673448E 0▒( 2673448
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include input and output as a text (not images).

Comment: You should use strdup to. copy the names.

Comment: I don't see any memory beeing allocated for `struct data`'s `name` field. Eighter allocate memory or make it a fixed size string in the struct declaration. Also `studentnode` is already a pointer, don't take it's address when you pass it to the `add_student` function.

Comment: You can copy and paste 100 lines of code, but not a 13 line output or a 14 line input file?

Answer (score 4):

```
studentnode = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

only allocates memory for an instance of `student`. The memory for `studentnode->d` has not been allocated. Therefore any `n->d->something` in `add_student()` is invalid, thus invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Nice catch -- also this `name` field of each student is merely shallow copying data from the stack in `readAndLoad` (not related to the immediate problem, but definitely another one).